# Speed up a 3X3 or 26X26 Kernel

Tags: c#, performance, convolution

Anyone have any suggestions on how to speed up a 3X3 or 26X26 Kernel in C#?

I believe that there must be a much better way to do this than by looping through each element in the array and calling `Laplacian3D()`

```
Parallel.For(0, field3D.XDimensions, paraOpts, i =>
{
    for (int j = 0; j < field3D.YDimensions; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < field3D.ZDimensions; k++)
        {
            field3D.NextField[i, j, k].FitnessVector = (1 - decayT) * Laplacian3D(i, j,k, field3D);
         }
     }
});
```

Does anyone have any good suggestions?

Comment: Depending on what `NextField` and `Laplacian3` are doing, you may by able to utilize [SIMD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector).

Comment: Theodor's idea sounds good but you may also be interested on some GPU acceleration. Take a look at http://www.ilgpu.net/.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Laplacian is just performing a parallel mean filter on a 26X26 neighborhood of my own vector class. Next field just stores a custom class. So is the Vector class that you are referencing supposed to be very performance driven? I noticed its an immutable type. Had know idea that namespace existed

Comment: @VictorOrtuondo thanks for the link! and it looks very reliable, have you used it before?

Comment: Typically with SIMD the performance of running a calculation in one core is a bit better than running the same calculation parallely in 4 cores. SIMD means executing a Single Instruction in Multiple Data, so parallelism occurs in a single core. The calculations are done so fast that you may find yourself constrained by other factors, like the bandwidth of the RAM. In my PC the property [`Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector.ishardwareaccelerated) becomes true only when I uncheck the "Prefer 32-bit" compilation option.

Comment: The only thing that worries me is that the Vector static class does not provide a Normalize method and I will need it. So if you have a collection of objects with SIMD it will do everything in one single execution instead of an execution per object?